# How to get starting year and ending year from list of date in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Here is my projects table. It has two fields id and project_created_date. I want to get starting year and ending year from project_created_date. In this case starting year is 2016 and ending year is 2018.

```
 -----------------------------------
|   ID  |   PROJECT_CREATED_DATE    |
 -----------------------------------
|   1   |       2018-07-11          |
 -----------------------------------
|   2   |       2018-07-13          |
 -----------------------------------
|   3   |       2018-07-23          |
 -----------------------------------
|   4   |       2016-12-14          |
 -----------------------------------
|   5   |       2017-07-31          |
 -----------------------------------
```

If I query like this I can get start and ending year.

```
 SELECT year(PROJECT_CREATED_DATE) as startYear FROM `projects` ORDER BY PROJECT_CREATED_DATE ASC LIMIT 1
 SELECT year(PROJECT_CREATED_DATE) as endYear FROM `projects` ORDER BY PROJECT_CREATED_DATE DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I want make the query into single one. I mean I want to get the result like this

```
  ------------------------------
|   startYear   |   endYear     |
 -------------------------------
|       2016    |     2018      |
 -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `min` and `max` function

```
      SELECT min(year(PROJECT_CREATED_DATE)) as  startYear,
        max(year(PROJECT_CREATED_DATE)) as EndYear FROM `projects`
```

Comment: I think this method is better than sub select. I forgot about min and max. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use sub-select like this

```
SELECT 
(SELECT year(PROJECT_CREATED_DATE) FROM `projects` ORDER BY PROJECT_CREATED_DATE ASC LIMIT 1) as startYear,
(SELECT year(PROJECT_CREATED_DATE) FROM `projects` ORDER BY PROJECT_CREATED_DATE DESC LIMIT 1) as endYear
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @AshisBiswas if my method better than you accept others answer :)